# Assigning the same key => value pair to multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, reference, variable-assignment

I'm trying to write a function that assigns the same **key => value** pair to multiple `array`s. But the assignment doesn't occur.

```php
<?php

// for debugging
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// arrays is an array of reference arrays
function assignKeyValueToArrays($arrays, $key, $value) {

    if(!is_scalar($key) || !is_array($arrays)) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach($arrays as $array) {
        if(!is_array($array)) return false;
        echo "setting $key to $value";
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }

}

$s = array();
$t = array();

assignKeyValueToArrays(array(&$s, &$t), "a", "blahblah");

// should print array(1) {"a" => "blahblah"} but both print array(0) {}
var_dump($s);
var_dump($t);

?>
```

The context for this is that I have a script which is doing database queries and assigns keys to both a temporary `$queryParams` array and also a `$jsonResponse` array. I could just do two assignments but I wanted a more general solution that could handle more arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass `$array` to the `foreach` loop by reference too, like `&$array`.

Checkout this [**Demo**](https://eval.in/233249)